# verify recaptcha gem rails using jquery

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, recaptcha

I render a partial contact form, and I am using the recaptcha gem. How can I verify the recaptca using jquery?

The form code is:

```
.content
  .contact
    %b
      %form#new_contact.new_contact{:action => "/contact", :method => "post"}
        = text_field_tag "user_info[name]", nil, placeholder: "Your Name", required: ""
        %br
        = text_field_tag "user_info[email]", nil, placeholder: "Your Email Address", type: "email", required: ""
        %br
        = text_field_tag "user_info[subject]", nil, placeholder: "Subject", required: ""
        %br
        = text_area_tag "user_info[message]", nil, placeholder: "Write your message here", required: ""
        =recaptcha_tags(display: {theme: 'clean'}, ajax: true)
        %button.btn.btn-primary.btn-large{type: 'submit'} Send
```

The controler code is:

```
def contact
    if verify_recaptcha(:model => @user, :message => "Oh! It's error with reCAPTCHA!")
      if Email.contactowner(params[:user_info]).deliver
        flash[:notice] = "Your message has been sent!"
      else
        flash[:notice] = "Your message has not being sent"
      end
      redirect_to request.referrer
    else
      redirect_to request.referrer
      flash[:notice] = 'The captcha that was entered is incorrect, please try again.'
      end
  end
```

Comment: " I want to verify the recaptca" - so verify  it...

Comment: in case you don't get my above comment - you a are posting a question here, but in your case there is no question, just a statement "I want to verify the recaptca using jquery".. so use it, no need to post it here. Or do you have problems with it, if so, write it in your question.